# ERROR running force:org:create: The requested resource does not exist

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

When I run this command I get the following error.

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a TestDevHub
sfdx force:org:create -a TestDevHub -s -v <developer_email> edition=Developer
```

The first command is successful and the second command is the error.

```
ERROR running force:org:create:  The requested resource does not exist
```

[image: Dev Hub]

Are there any ideas for this error?
Thank you

Comment: Have you activated the Dev Hub feature in your `TestDevHub` org? Also note that you'll want to change the value of `-a` in your second command to give your scratch org a different alias.

Comment: I am a junior salesforce developer. How can I check to activate the Dev Hub feature in `TestDevHub` org?

Comment: @DavidReed Could you let me know how I can create `TestDevHub` org?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must [Enable Dev Hub](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_setup_enable_devhub.htm) in your production or developer edition org before you can use it to create scratch orgs.

If you are new to Salesforce DX, start with the [App Development with Salesforce DX](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sfdx_app_dev) module on Trailhead.

Comment: I've checked the Dev Hub. I think it's enabled. Could you let me know how to create the Dev Hub?

Comment: If you have an org with Dev Hub enabled, you do not need to create one.

Comment: If so, where can I see the org name of Dev Hub?

Comment: If you're trying to find the name of an org that is connected to your SFDX keychain, use `sfdx force:org:list`

Comment: thank you @David

Answer (score 2):

The reason I was getting this error is because I forgot to assign the correct scratch org permissions to my user.

```
Object Settings > Scratch Org Infos > Read, Create, Edit, and Delete
Object Settings > Active Scratch Orgs > Read, Edit, and Delete
Object Settings > Namespace Registries > Read
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm#sfdx_setup_permission_set.xml